# Copy to clipboard cannot paste

Tags: javascript, html, clipboard, clipboarddata

I tried below code and run it. It seems I can create ClipboardEvent successfully to copy information. But, I could not paste it using Ctrl+V in MS Word.

Browser : Firefox (v35.0.1)

```
            // behavior to copy elements with format
            $("#copy-formatted").click(function(e){
                var text = $("#container").html();
                console.log(text);

                // first attempt => data is successfully saved to copyEvent
                /*var copyEvent = new ClipboardEvent('copy', { dataType: 'text/plain', data: text } );
                console.log(copyEvent);
                document.dispatchEvent(copyEvent);*/

                // ClipboardEvent is not recognized by IE11
                var clip = new ClipboardEvent('copy');
                clip.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', "test");
                clip.preventDefault();
                clip.returnValue = false;

                // *********************************** //
                // data is successfully retrieved here //
                // *********************************** //
                console.log(clip.clipboardData.getData('text/plain'));

                // *** > dispatching not sure how this works. seems not working.
                //e.target.dispatchEvent(clip);
                document.dispatchEvent(clip);


                console.log("finished dispatching event");
            });
```

Please help.

Comment: Is there any console errors?

Comment: There are no console errors.